# How to define a variable in a function when calling the function?

Tags: python, mean, standard-deviation, variance

When I run my code I get “NameError: name ‘mean’ is not defined”. I get this error when I try to call my function “calculateVariance(mean, nums)”. I can not seem to figure out how I can define ‘mean’ without having to changing my “calculateVariance(mean, nums)”  function.. if that makes sense..

Here is the code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readFile(file_name):

    with open('data_1.txt', 'r') as DataOne:
    nums = DataOne.read()
    
    print(nums)

    return nums

def calculateMean(nums):

    sumOfNums = 0

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        sumOfNums += i
    
    mean = sumOfNums//len(nums)

    print("The mean is : ", mean)

    return mean

def calculateVariance(mean, nums):

    squaredDifferences = 0

    for number in nums:
        difference =mean - number
        squaredDiff = difference ** 2
        squaredDifferences += squaredDiff
    variance = squaredDifferences // (len(nums)-1)

    print(" The variance is : ", variance)

    return variance

def calculateSD(variance):
 
    square_root = math.sqrt(number)
    StandDev = square_root(variance)

    print("Standard Deviation is : ", StandDev)

    return StandDev

def showHistogram(nums):

    num_bins = 10
    plt.hist(listOfNums, num_bins)
    plt.show()

nums = readFile('data_1.txt')
calculateMean(nums)
calculateVariance(mean, nums)
calculateSD(variance)
```

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**. Also your indentation is incorrect. Is that a copy/paste error or is it your actual code? The `return` statements should be indented so that they belong to the function.

Comment: If you define `mean` inside the function `calculateMean()` it will be local to that function only. Which means it can't be used outside the function.  Assuming the indentation problems are just a typos, you should use the returned value from `calculateMean()` — something like `mean = calculateMean(nums)`.

Comment: FYI if you use `pandas` package, these are just one-liner calls: `nums.mean()`, `nums.var()`

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the function which returns `mean`, you are not actually saving it. Therefore it cannot be used when calling a different function.

Try saving it as `mean_result` or similar to use for later (avoiding naming clashes).

Answer (score 0):

You should store `mean` result from function `calculateMean(nums)` in a variable. You need to do it for another function as well.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readFile(file_name):
    with open('data_1.txt', 'r') as DataOne:
    nums = DataOne.readlines()
    print(nums)
    return nums

def calculateMean(nums):
    sumOfNums = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        sumOfNums += i
    
    mean = sumOfNums//len(nums)
    print("The mean is : ", mean)
    return mean

def calculateVariance(mean, nums):
    squaredDifferences = 0
    for number in nums:
        if number != '':
            difference = mean - int(number.replace('\n', ''))
            squaredDiff = difference ** 2
            squaredDifferences += squaredDiff
    variance = squaredDifferences // (len(nums)-1)
    print(" The variance is : ", variance)
    return variance

def calculateSD(variance):
    square_root = math.sqrt(number)
    StandDev = math.sqrt(variance)
    print("Standard Deviation is : ", StandDev)

    return StandDev

def showHistogram(nums):
    num_bins = 10
    plt.hist(listOfNums, num_bins)
    plt.show()

nums = readFile('data_1.txt')
mean = calculateMean(nums)
variance = calculateVariance(mean, nums)
stdev = calculateSD(variance)
```

Comment: when I do this I get "Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "N:\Fall 2021\DataScience Intro to Python\Lab 12\SDandHistogram.py", line 76, in <module>
    variance = calculateVariance(mean_result, nums)

  File "N:\Fall 2021\DataScience Intro to Python\Lab 12\SDandHistogram.py", line 45, in calculateVariance
    difference = mean_result - number

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'" Is there any way I can fix this? When I try to do int(number) it gives me another error saying "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n' "

Comment: sorry, my previous comment won't let me edit

Comment: try change `mean - number` to  `mean - int(number.replace('\n', ''))`

Comment: It seems there is newline or `\n` in each row on txt reader

Comment: when i do this i get "
  File "N:\Fall 2021\DataScience Intro to Python\Lab 12\SDandHistogram.py", line 37, in calculateVariance
    difference = mean - int(numbers.replace('\n', ''))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' "

Comment: It caused by the last line in the txt, you should ignore it